# How to customise the Control_SearchResults.html to change the href link

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, display-template

I would like to change the url link/path that is returned in search results based on the list name.
I have downloaded a copy of the Control_SearchResults and the item_Default templates i just don't know what to change in these files

Currently let us say i have the below url returned

/sites/mySite/Lists/EventType/DispForm.aspx?ID=2

I would like to change it to

/sites/mySite/Item/custombul.aspx?bId=5

or 
/sites/mySite/Lists/NewsType/DispForm.aspx?ID=2

I would like to change it to

/sites/mySite/Item/customNewsType.aspx?bId=5

Any ideas how to do this or any resources would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could customize below file to change the url/Path.

[image]

[image]

You could check below thread for demo.

https://medium.com/@frankchen2016/apply-custom-logic-for-all-display-templates-a0100ec7beeb

Comment: Thanks Lee and i got to that display template but not sure how i can customise it to suit my needs e.g if the results is from a particular list e.g reports change the url to my custom page e.g /MySite/ItemPages/reports.aspx?bid=1.

So i need the item ID too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use developer tool, you could debug the variables(item_yourdisplaytemplate.js), so you could inject custom  JavaScript to check the url, if url continas list(ItemPages), then update it.